# Default dictionary with lists in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

Is there a way to have a `Dictionary` in C# that will automatically have an empty list associated with any key, other than creating such a class myself? I would like to avoid the following code if possible:

```
int x = 0;
int y = 42;
Dictionary<int, List<int>> dict = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

List<int> newList;
if (dict.containsKey(x))
{
    dict[x].Add(y);
}
else
{
    dict[x] = new List<int>{y};
}
```

or possibly:

```
int x = 0;
int y = 42;
Dictionary<int, List<int>> dict = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

List<int> newList;
if (dict.TryGetValue(x, out newList))
{
    newList.Add(y);
}
else
{
    dict[x] = new List<int>{y};
}
```

Comment: You could just wrap the above code in an extension method

Comment: @Harold Makes sense, I just wanted to check if there's a built-in way, like there is in python.

Comment: `Dictionary` doesn't have that, but `MMap` from `Loyc` library has `AddOrFind` method. https://github.com/qwertie/ecsharp/blob/master/Core/Loyc.Collections/Sets/MMap.cs

Comment: If your keys are known beforehand perhaps `.ToDictionary` might be helpful:  `Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToDictionary(x => x, y => new List<int>())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior can be abstracted nicely with an extension method.

```
public static TValue GetOrAdd<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key, Func<TKey, TValue> valueFactory)
{
    if (dictionary == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dictionary));
    if (valueFactory == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(valueFactory));

    TValue value;
    if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value))
    {
        value = valueFactory.Invoke(key);
        dictionary.Add(key, value);
    }
    return value;
}
```

The method signature is identical to `ConcurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd()`.

```
var list = dict.GetOrAdd(x, (_) => new List<int>());
list.Add(y);
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually my code is:

```
if (!dict.containsKey(x)) 
    dict[x] = new List<int>();

dict[x].Add(y);
```

I believe it's easier to read

Comment: This causes 2 lookups instead of 1 when using `TryGetValue`.

Comment: It's also adding `y` twice in the "doesn't initially contain key" case...

Comment: @owairc: I don't think you were really replying to my comment, although you've now fixed the code. But if you were trying to reply to xxbbcc's comment, this *isn't* optimized at compile time. There really would be two lookups.

Answer (score 0):

you already have answer, dictionary does not have such ability, using extension method just fakes it and hides the fact that you are looking up dictionary twice (in case key doesn't exist). but you will write one line of code if that makes you happy.

In c#7 how ever you can pack things more a little bit.

```
if (dict.TryGetValue(x, out var list)) list.Add(y);
else dict.Add(x, new List<int>{y});
```

this will have one lookup if key already exist, and two lookups if key doesn't exist.